# Quebra Cabeça com array e modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, array, mysqli

Então eu tenho uma pagina que mostra um total de 8 divs por paginação, essas divs tem pequenas informações dentro, elas possuem 2 button que permite deletar e ter mais informações sobre o que está dentro da div que no caso e os dados de um número de telefone, o problema e o seguinte, dessas 8 divs eu consigo ver as 2 primeiras normalmente: digo ver as informações do número, porém nas outras 6 aparece a mesma informação que está dentro da segunda div... eu acho que o problema e no if mais não consigo resolver, segue o código:

```html
<?php 
    include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados
     
    //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; 
 
    //seleciona todos os itens da tabela 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
 
    //conta o total de itens 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
 
    //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens 
    $registros = 8; 
 
    //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima 
    $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros); 
 
    //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual 
    $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros; 
 
    //seleciona os itens por página 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros limit $inicio,$registros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
     
    //exibe os produtos selecionados 
    
        echo "<div class='container'>
    <div class='row pricing text-center'>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
    <div class='well'>

    ";
    $cont=0;
     while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)){
      if (($cont%8)==0):
        
                           
                 echo "<h3><b>".$produto['numero']."</b></h3>
       <hr>
      <p>Chip:&nbsp;".$produto['nchip']."</p>
      <hr>
      <p>IMEI:&nbsp;".$produto['imei']."</p>
      <hr>
      <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>
      
      
    <div class='modal fade' id='info' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
     <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
     <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Telefone</h3>
     
    <div class='modal-body'>
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' value=".$produto['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-4'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
       
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['rca']." style='text-align: center;' maxlength='4' readonly='readonly' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)' required>
      </div>
     </div>
       
       <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' required>
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='usuario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
    
    </div>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     </div>
     </div>
    "; 
           
     else :
     echo"<div class='col-md-3'>
      <div class='well'> 
      <h3><b>".$produto['numero']."</b></h3>
       <hr>
      <p>Chip:&nbsp;".$produto['nchip']."</p>
      <hr>
      <p>IMEI:&nbsp;".$produto['imei']."</p>
      <hr>
      <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class=' glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info2' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>
      
      <div class='modal fade' id='info2' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
     <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
     <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Telefone</h3>
     
    <div class='modal-body'>
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' value=".$produto['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-4'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
       
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['rca']." style='text-align: center;' maxlength='4' readonly='readonly' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)' required>
      </div>
     </div>
       
       <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' required>
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
      <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
      <input type='text' name='usuario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
      <br></div>
     </div>
     
    
    </div>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     ";
     
     
      endif;
    $cont++;
     }for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
     echo "<div class='row'>
              <div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>
  <li><a href='visualizarn.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li></ul></div></div> "; 
    } 
 echo"
  </div>
 ";
  
         
?>
```

Comment: vai ser mais facil  vc inspensionar o  html  aperta f12 e procura deve ter alguma div colocando  hierarquia sobre a outra

Comment: -não entendi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que a tag que abre o modal a partir da terceira iteração do while é sempre `<a href='#`info2`'...` e isso quer dizer, mostre a div cujo id é igual a `info2`.

A solução é incrementar o numero após o termo `info`, ou seja, `<a href='#info".$cont."'`. Aproveitei a variável  `$cont` que já existe no seu código e que a cada iteração ela já é incrementada.

Observar que as `<div class='modal fade' id='info2'` devem ter o valor do id correspondente a tag que a chama, portanto deve concatenar também o valor de `$cont` a cada iteração `<div class='modal fade' id='info".$cont."'`.

> Aproveitei acertei seu HTML, ( assim penso eu :D ), que continha mais tags de abertura `div` que de fechamento `</div>` e retirei o if else que é desnecessário.

```
//exibe os produtos selecionados 

    echo "<div class='container'>
            <div class='row pricing text-center'>

            ";
            $cont=0;
                while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)){

                    echo"<div class='col-md-3'>
                    <div class='well'>";


             echo "<h3><b>".$produto['numero']."</b></h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Chip:&nbsp;".$produto['nchip']."</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>IMEI:&nbsp;".$produto['imei']."</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                    <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info".$cont."' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>


<div class='modal fade' id='info".$cont."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
                <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Telefone</h3>

            <div class='modal-body'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' value=".$produto['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['rca']." style='text-align: center;' maxlength='4' readonly='readonly' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)' required>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='usuario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>


            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
             </div>
             </div>
             ";


            $cont++;
                }

            for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
                echo "<div class='row'>
          <div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>
    <li><a href='visualizarn.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li></ul></div></div> "; 
            } 
echo"
    </div></div>
";
```